# Nuget Config.Transform Formatting Issue

Tags: web-config, nuget, app-config

I have created a [Nuget config transform file](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations) that has the following transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IMyService" />
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://mydomain/MySvc/MySvc.svc"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IMyService"
                contract="MyNamespace.MyService" name="NetTcpBinding_IMyService">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="admin@mydomain.com" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The problem occurs when it merges into an application's app.config or web.config file.  Instead of being cleanly spaced it joins everything into one line as follows:

```
    <system.serviceModel><bindings><netTcpBinding><binding name="NetTcpBinding_IMyService" /></netTcpBinding></bindings><client><endpoint address="net.tcp://mydomain/MySvc/MySvc.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IMyService" contract="MyNamespace.MyService" name="NetTcpBinding_IMyService"><identity><userPrincipalName value="admin@mydomain.com" />                    </identity></endpoint></client></system.serviceModel>
```

This is not very readable to those consuming my package.  Is there something I am missing?  Proper carriage returns perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

There are formatting limitations in the original Web.config transforms of NuGet.  As of v2.6, XDT transforms have been added which don't have these limitations.  See the [docs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations) on how to use the `.install.xdt` and `.uninstall.xdt` files for any XML files in your package.  Once I started using XDT, formatting issues went away.

Comment: It's worth noting, that the xdt transformations are not supported in PackageReference - "As mentioned in the package compatibility issues section of the docs for migrating from packages.config to PackageReference, XDT transformations as described below are only supported by packages.config. If you add the below files to your package, consumers using your package with PackageReference will not have the transformations applied (refer to this sample to make XDT transforms work withPackageReference)."