# How to use .xdt file

Tags: nuget-package, xdt-transform

I have followed the following post [Nuget Config.Transform Formatting Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971083/nuget-config-transform-formatting-issue) to add web.config file entries in NuGet.

I have used the below xdt file in my NuGet package

```
    <compilation>
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="ASSEMBLY1, Version=1.0.10, Culture=neutral" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
            <add assembly="ASSEMBLY2, Version=1.0.11, Culture=neutral" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
            <add assembly="ASSEMBLY3, Version=1.0.12, Culture=neutral" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
            <add assembly="ASSEMBLY4, Version=1.0.13, Culture=neutral" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

and i have tried to install this NuGet am getting the following error. Error An error occurred while applying transformation to 'web.config' in project 'WebApplication60' No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.web/compilation/assemblies/add' 0

Since the assemblies node was not found in the project. I have tried to add xdt:Transform="Insert" to assemblies node, but it causes duplicate entries in web.configfile like below

```
<assemblies>
                <add assembly="ASSEMBLY1, Version=1.0.10, Culture=neutral" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
                <add assembly="ASSEMBLY2, Version=1.0.11, Culture=neutral" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
                <add assembly="ASSEMBLY3, Version=1.0.12, Culture=neutral" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
                <add assembly="ASSEMBLY4, Version=1.0.13, Culture=neutral" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
<add assembly="ASSEMBLY1, Version=1.0.10, Culture=neutral" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
                <add assembly="ASSEMBLY2, Version=1.0.11, Culture=neutral" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
                <add assembly="ASSEMBLY3, Version=1.0.12, Culture=neutral" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
                <add assembly="ASSEMBLY4, Version=1.0.13, Culture=neutral" xdt:Transform="Insert"/>
            </assemblies>
```

How to avoid this duplicate entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid inserting duplicate entries, you can try to remove `assemblies` element first, if any, then insert a new one which has been populated with `<add assembly=""/>` elements afterwards :

```
<compilation>
    <assemblies xdt:Transform="Remove"/>
    <assemblies xdt:Transform="Insert">
        <add assembly="ASSEMBLY1, Version=1.0.10, Culture=neutral"/>
        <add assembly="ASSEMBLY2, Version=1.0.11, Culture=neutral"/>
        <add assembly="ASSEMBLY3, Version=1.0.12, Culture=neutral"/>
        <add assembly="ASSEMBLY4, Version=1.0.13, Culture=neutral"/>
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Or, you can try using `InsertIfMissing` transform to insert while an element and avoid duplicate in case it already exists :

```
<compilation>
    <assemblies xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <add assembly="ASSEMBLY1, Version=1.0.10, Culture=neutral" 
             xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(assembly)"/>
        <add assembly="ASSEMBLY2, Version=1.0.11, Culture=neutral"
             xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(assembly)"/>
        <add assembly="ASSEMBLY3, Version=1.0.12, Culture=neutral"
             xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(assembly)"/>
        <add assembly="ASSEMBLY4, Version=1.0.13, Culture=neutral"
             xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(assembly)"/>
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: if we do so, the whole assemblies entries will get remove right?if i already having the following entry in my web.config file in  the sense <assemblies>
        <add assembly="ASSEMBLY-old, Version=1.0.10, Culture=neutral"/>
        <
    </assemblies> It will be removed while installing the NuGet, that is not desirable

Comment: I thought the initial problem ('No element in the source document matches...') was because web.config doesn't contain `assemblies` element yet?

Comment: @user3610920 Posted an alternative which uses `InsertIfMissing` transform. Only tested in asp.net project in VS2012, so far. Curious whether it will work with nuget xdt as well.. Please confirm. Thanks

Comment: @user3610920 And please consider accepting the answer since it provides a working solution (seeing your questions history, I think I need to mention this). For more explanation please refer to [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) . Thanks